# AWS RDS MSSQL cannot alter the availability group 'RDSAG0'. because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

In AWS RDS MSSQL we have mirroring running between primary and replica via Always On.
We want to remove/drop a couple of databases, but when we try:

`ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP RDSAG0 REMOVE DATABASE [db-name]`

we receive the error:

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Cannot alter the availability group 'RDSAG0', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

[image]

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: might help to say what permissions you have when running the command (& check them on the secondary too)

Comment: Additionally knowing if the databases you want to drop are part of the availability group, and what your drop scripts are, would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

AWS RDS has some platform-specific commands which you should familiarize yourself with. Running EXECUTE msdb.dbo.rds_drop_database  N'your-database-name' will perform all of the tasks necessary to remove the database from the AG and then drop it. Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.DropMirrorDB.html